# Custom Input File Jquery Plugin

Tags: html, jquery

Utilizo una biblioteca para adjuntar archivos, me funciona bien. Mi problema radica que esos elementos los tengo en un DIV que inicialmente están invisible, y desde jquery lo muestro u oculto dependiendo del valor seleccionado de otro elemento, lo que necesito es que cuando se oculten los div, si se ha adjuntado algún documento se elimine.

```
<!--JCrop (Jquery plugin for cropping images)-->
<script src="recursos/js/custominputfile/jquery.Jcrop.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="recursos/css/custominputfile/jquery.Jcrop.min.css" type="text/css" /> 

<!--Custom Input File-->
<script src="recursos/js/custominputfile/custominputfile.min.js"></script> 
<link rel="stylesheet" href="recursos/css/custominputfile/custominputfile.min.css"  type="text/css" />


<fieldset class="fieldset" style="display: none;" id="fadjuntos">
     <legend>Archivos Adjuntos</legend>
     <div class="form-row row">
         <div class="form-group col-md-6" style="display: none;" id="td_rut">
             <label for="">RUT</label>&nbsp;<label for="" style="color: red;"><strong>*</strong></label>
             <input name="input-file-1" id="input-file-1"><br>
             <p><small><strong>Archivos de subida&nbsp;:&nbsp;</strong>(Archivos de subida como jpg,&nbsp;jpeg,&nbsp;png,&nbsp;gif,&nbsp;pdf)<br>Maximo tamaño por archivo 10MB</strong></small></p>
         </div>
         <div class="form-group col-md-6" style="display: none;" id="td_soporte">
             <label for="">Soporte de Pago</label>&nbsp;<label for="" style="color: red;"><strong>*</strong></label>
             <input name="input-file-2" id="input-file-2"><br>
             <p><small><strong>Archivos de subida&nbsp;:&nbsp;</strong>(Archivos de subida como jpg,&nbsp;jpeg,&nbsp;png,&nbsp;gif,&nbsp;pdf)<br>Maximo tamaño por archivo 10MB</strong></small></p>
         </div>
     </div>
</fieldset>
```

En esta parte configuro el input.

```
$('#input-file-1').customFile({
    type: 'all',
    allowed: ["gif", "jpeg", "jpg", "png", "pdf"],
    notAllowed: ['exe', 'js', 'css', 'php'],
    messages: {
        errorType: 'Tipo de archivo no permitido',
        errorMaxMB: 'El archivo pesa más de 10MB',
    },
    maxFiles: 0,
    maxMB: 10,
    callbacks: {
        onComplete: function(app) {
            validar_archivo_rut = app.itemFileList.length;
        },
        beforeRemove: function(item) {
            validar_archivo_rut = 0;
        },
    },
});
```

Y lo siguiente es un ejemplo de como lo muestro, dependiendo de un valor

```
$(document).on('changed.bs.select', '#forma_pago', function (e, clickedIndex, isSelected, previousValue) {
    var forma = $(this).val();
    if (forma === "2") {//Si el pago es por transferencia
        $('#fadjuntos').show(); //Se muestra en DIV para cargar soporte de pago
        $('#td_soporte').show();
    }else{
        $('#td_soporte').hide();
        $('#fadjuntos').hide(); //Se esconde en DIV para cargar soporte de pago
    }
});
```

Lo que necesito es que cuando se oculte el div, se elimine cualquier archivo adjunto que se haya seleccionado. Estuve mirando la página oficial:
[introducir la descripción del vínculo aquí](https://www.aesolucionesweb.com.ar/developers/custom-file-jquery-plugin#presentation)
Y encontré que cuenta con un método público llamado item.destroy() pero no logro hacerlo funcionar. Si alguien ha usado esta biblioteca y sabe como hacerlo, les agradecería.

Comment: dijate que en este caso, tendrias que ir a la documentacion y averiguar si tiene un metodo para destruir el objeto o la relacion elemento pluggin... y si piensas hacer eso tendrias tambien que programar que cada vez que se hace visible el input es cuando debes de inicializar el pluggin en el elemento...